# JSONP callback issue

Tags: html, callback, jsonp

I'm trying to get JSONP working with a server running on an Arduino.
This is my JS code:

```
window.onload = init;

function init()
{
    //alert("Test");
    SendRequest();
}

function SendRequest()
{
    alert("Sending request");
    var url = "http://192.168.1.177";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.error = function(e) {
            alert("ERROR");
        };
    request.send(null);
}


function ArduinoJSONP()
{
    alert("Callback received!!!");
}
```

The callback function is never reached.

But if I just direct my browser directly to the Arduino IP I see the following displayed in the browser:

```
ArduinoJSONP({"data": 12345})
```

So it seems the server is sending the response with correct JSONP format but somehow the function is not invoked. Is there anything else I need to for JS to call the function? I even tried moving the function to the HTML body but it didn't help either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling server response at all. If you doing it without any libraries you need to `eval` result that was returned by the server.

And actually JSONP implementation is not XHR, you have to inject it as a script tag into html with correct src attribute.

Just use a library that already have all this logic abstracted for you.

Simply inject script tag into HTML tree:

```
function SendRequest()
{
    var element = document.createElement('script'); 
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    element.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    element.async = true;
    element.src = 'http://192.168.1.177';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(element, s);
}
```

You can mark it with unique id. Hookup to onload event and once executed remove that script.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this so please bear with me about the details. You are right. JSONP is not XHR but the Arduino server cannot handle a JSONP request so I'm using a XHR just to make a connection to the Arduino server. The server will see a connection from a client and reply with the JSONP.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I was not aware of the need for the 'script' element. Will read more in to this. Thank you very much.